# Reading an excel sheet with Pandas, while maintaining the original (unrounded) values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read an excel sheet with pandas, and create a dataframe.

As an example, let's say this is my table in the sheet of my .xlsx file:

[image]

I read the excel sheet into a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=sheet_number)
```

The result I get looks like this:

```
      Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2
0        NaN   variable      value
1        NaN       test       1.04
```

Regardless of the structure of the table, I want have the original values from the excel sheet, so **104.00%** instead of 1.04. I know I can specify certain columns and rows to a specific format. But this is not what I'm after, as the position of the values in the sheet can sometime vary. Is there a way for me to just read the original values (like in string format for example), without having to specify the exact format for each individual column or row?

I've tried to do it like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=page_number, dtype=str)
```

But without any success..

Comment: You want to see 104.00% only as string in dataframe. Meaning you wouldn't use that for any other calculations or making plots ?

Comment: I just want the true value of each cell from the sheet, regardless of what the type of the content of that cell is. But I do need to maintain the structure of the table in the sheet, therefore I need the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format pandas dataframe only for looks.
Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Value":[1.04, 1, 0.2], "Category":['A', 'B', 'C']})
df["Value"] = df["Value"].map('{:.2%}'.format)

#Output
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for the reply! But this is not really what I meant. It is not only for the looks but I need the original values from the excel sheet. Without specifying what type of format each particular cell has, since this differs within my sheet and would not be maintainable.

Comment: Pandas do not have percentage dtype. Instead of percentage, you see float. You work with floats until you need to export data or show it somewhere like plots. You format float as string which looks like percentage later on if you send data. If you export float to Excel and later format Excel cells to percentage, you would see same result as when you read Excel.

Comment: I understand, but this is just an simplification of the problem. In my case I have a big excel sheet, from which I need to import my data into Python. Therefore I read the excel sheet into a dataframe. I'm just looking for a generic approach to import that data the way it is stored in the excel sheet. I don't really care what type it is, but I believe a string would be most suitable, just to catch the 104.00% instead of it getting converted to 1.04...

Comment: My solution convert float to strings. And you do get data in dataframe same as it's in Excel. It's also a float in excel, only that it's visually formated.